# React Hook Form and setValue of file input

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm facing issue with setting the value of file input with multiple files choice.

In a form i have two file input fields, one allows user to select only one file, and the second allow multiple files.
So while applying setValue to the singular file input, it works fine and file goes to state, but at the same time, while i trying to setValue for the multiple files input, i get the following error **"Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string."**

```
 const handleSingle = (file, uploadedData) => {
   setValue("single", file);
   };

   const handleMultiple = (files, data) => {
   setValue('multiple', [...files]);
  };
```

Of course, the "multiple" field in the form should be an array of file objects, but i can't figure out what is the issue.

Comment: Well i added "value={ undefined }" to file input with multiple choice and now it works, but don't know why and how good it is.

Answer (score 0):

Well I added `value={ undefined }` to file input with multiple choice and now it works. I don't know why and how good it is, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the value of input where 'type' is 'file'. input.value can only be set by the user.

Below case works well, because you didn't change users input.

```
export default function App() {
  const [v, setV] = useState("");

  return (
    <input
      type="file"
      onChange={(e) => {
        setV(e.target.value);    <--- pass exactly same value
      }}
      value={v}                  <-- not changed
    />
  );
}
```

I think your error case is like:

```
export default function App() {
  const [v, setV] = useState("");

  return (
    <input
      multiple
      type="file"
      onChange={(e) => {
        setV(e.target.files);
      }}
      value={v} <-------------- error
    />
  );
}
```

You don't need to set value in this case. If you want to sync input with React state, you can set 'files'

```
export default function App() {
  const [v, setV] = useState();

  return (
    <input
      multiple
      type="file"
      onChange={(e) => {
        setV(e.target.files);
      }}
      files={v} <-------------- files, not value
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: But why it works with single file input then?

Comment: @Vahe I updated answer. Check it out.